# Series of correlation matrices in R

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

Given the following baby fragment:

```
d1=as.Date('April 26, 2001',format='%B %d, %Y')
d2=as.Date('April 27, 2001',format='%B %d, %Y')
d3=as.Date('April 28, 2001',format='%B %d, %Y')
tibble(DATE=c(d1,d1,d2,d2,d3,d3), Symbol=c("A","B","A","B","A","B"), voladj=c(0.2, 0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.3, 0.2))
```

resulting in

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  DATE       Symbol voladj
  <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
1 2001-04-26 A         0.2
2 2001-04-26 B         0.3
3 2001-04-27 A        -0.2
4 2001-04-27 B        -0.1
5 2001-04-28 A         0.3
6 2001-04-28 B         0.2
```

I try to compute a series of correlation/covariance matrices cor at time D2, cor at time D3, ... etc. Ideally data is exponentially weighted. What options do I have in R? To make things a bit more spicy a Symbol C may at some point show up, too. I was thinking to compute the outer product (rank 1 matrix) at time t1, t2, t3, and then use a simple moving mean.

A potential output could be the following:

```
  DATE       cov
  <date>     
1 2001-04-26  M1
2 2001-04-27  M2
3 2001-04-28  M3
```

where M_i are matrices (or frames), such as

```
M_1 =    A    B
      A  1.0  c1

      B  c1   1.0
```

etc.
Obviously more interesting once more symbols are involved

Comment: What output are you trying to produce? Aside from `voladj`, what other numeric variables go into the covariance matrices?

Comment: We try to compute the covariance of volatility adjusted returns per symbol. So here I am expecting a series of 2 x 2 matrices

Comment: Can you include the output you want? I can't tell what you'd be calculating, and how you're trying to group it (by date and symbol?)

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer, given comments

Here is an approach using `quantmod` to retrieve 5 stocks for three weeks from Yahoo Finance. We combine the `Close` variable from the `xts` objects into a data frame, generate `week` identifiers with `lubridate::week()`, `split()` it by week, and calculate covariance matrices for each week using `lapply()`.

```
library(quantmod)
from.dat <- as.Date("12/03/19",format="%m/%d/%y")
to.dat <- as.Date("12/24/19",format="%m/%d/%y")

theSymbols <- c("AAPL","AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO")
getSymbols(theSymbols,from=from.dat,to=to.dat,src="yahoo")

#combine to single data frame
combinedData <- data.frame(date = as.Date(rownames(as.data.frame(AAPL))),
                           AAPL$AAPL.Close,
                           AXP$AXP.Close,
                           BA$BA.Close,
                           CAT$CAT.Close,
                           CSCO$CSCO.Close)
colnames(combinedData) <- c("date","AAPL","AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO")
# split by week
library(lubridate)
combinedData$week <- week(combinedData$date)
symbolsByWeek <- split(combinedData,as.factor(combinedData$week))
covariances <- lapply(symbolsByWeek,function(x){
        cov(x[,-c(1,7)])
})
covariances[[1]]
```

...and the output:

```
> covariances[[1]]
           AAPL        AXP         BA        CAT        CSCO
AAPL 19.4962156  7.0959976  3.9093027  5.4158116 -0.66194433
AXP   7.0959976  3.0026695  2.0175793  2.2569625 -0.18793832
BA    3.9093027  2.0175793 10.4511473  1.8555752  0.55619975
CAT   5.4158116  2.2569625  1.8555752  1.8335361 -0.11141911
CSCO -0.6619443 -0.1879383  0.5561997 -0.1114191  0.07287982
>
```

### Original answer

Here is an approach using `quantmod` to retrieve Dow 30 data for four days from Yahoo Finance, `apply()` and `do.call()` with `rbind()` to massage it into a single data frame, and `split()` to split by day to produce daily covariance matrices.

```
library(quantmod)
from.dat <- as.Date("12/02/19",format="%m/%d/%y")
to.dat <- as.Date("12/06/19",format="%m/%d/%y")

theSymbols <- c("AAPL","AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO","CVX","XOM","GS","HD","IBM",
                "INTC","JNJ","KO","JPM","MCD","MMM","MRK","MSFT","NKE","PFE","PG",
                "TRV","UNH","UTX","VZ","V","WBA","WMT","DIS","DOW")
getSymbols(theSymbols,from=from.dat,to=to.dat,src="yahoo")
# since quantmod::getSymbols() writes named xts objects, need to use
# get() with the symbol names to access each data frame
# e.g. head(get(theSymbols[[1]]))
# convert to list
symbolData <- lapply(theSymbols,function(x){
     y <- as.data.frame(get(x))
     colnames(y) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adjusted")
     # add date and symbol name to output data frames 
     y$date <- rownames(y)
     y$symbol <- x
     y
})
#combine to single data frame
combinedData <- do.call(rbind,symbolData)
# split by day
symbolsByDay <- split(combinedData,as.factor(combinedData$date))
covariances <- lapply(symbolsByDay,function(x){
     cov(x[,1:6]) # only use first 6 columns 
})
# print first covariance matrix
covariances[1]
```

...and the output:

```
> covariances[1]
$`2019-12-02`
                  open          high           low         close        volume      adjusted
open          5956.289      5962.359      5811.514      5818.225 -9.274871e+07      5809.939
high          5962.359      5968.557      5817.580      5824.272 -9.314473e+07      5816.005
low           5811.514      5817.580      5671.809      5678.470 -9.188418e+07      5670.276
close         5818.225      5824.272      5678.470      5685.467 -9.155485e+07      5677.246
volume   -92748711.735 -93144729.578 -91884178.312 -91554853.356  4.365841e+13 -90986549.261
adjusted      5809.939      5816.005      5670.276      5677.246 -9.098655e+07      5669.171

>
```

Comment: thank you. We want a covariance matrix for only the close, the columns and rows would correspond to the symbols

Comment: If there is one and only one data element per symbol per day and each covariance matrix represents a single day, there are not enough degrees of freedom to calculate a covariance between two or more stock symbols. Could you explain how you plan to address the degrees of freedom issue? One way might be to increase the time period included in each matrix from one day to a week or month.

Comment: I don't compute covariance for slices of constant T. At time t_n I compute the covariance of returns I have observed at t1,t2,t3,...t_n. So we are talking time series data with n points.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on the sample data you posted, it appeared there was one and only one observation per stock symbol per day.

Comment: To simulate the t1 - t_n, I split the data by week. Also, since we're only interested in the Close data, I create the combined data frame directly from the `xts` objects retrieved from Yahoo Finance.

Comment: The sad news is that it's just a one-liner in pandas: cor = returns_adj.ewm(com=200).cov()

Comment: There is some useful stuff in your corrected answer. However, what you are essentially doing is split the time into subperiods and compute for each subperiod the one and only covariance matrix. In particular this subperiod needs at least as many days as you have assets (assuming daily data). Each additional day will essentially induce a small correction in your covariance matrix (which you could interpret as a moving average on the outer products of return vectors)...

Comment: @tschm Thanks for the feedback. As coded above, each subperiod includes 5 days for 5 stocks, so it conforms to the requirements stated in your most recent requirement.